# Use Angular 2 service from regular JS in browser

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 Service, meaning a typescript class that some components are using, which get data from a web service via http.
The ng service is using Angular's http, and rxjs Observables and observable operators.
I need to re-use this ng service in an entirely different application which is vanilla JS (no angular, no typescript).

Is it possible to compile only the ng service and it's dependencies (http, rxjs) and package it into a standalone self-sufficient JavaScript module which can be used in browser?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why it may not work

Comment: How do I do that? Do I just take the JS output of the service.ts file and try to use it outside Angular context? that surely won't work as it relies in Angular stuff, question is what other angular stuff I need and if there's an easy way to package it

Comment: if you're using modules, you already know what you need by inspecting imports. does your service uses dependency injection?

Comment: Yes. I only inject @angular/http, but also use other modules like rxjs, and some model classes. I know what my service depends on, but I don't know how to bootstrap *just* my service without the rest of the Angular app (and without requiring Angular as a dependency)

Comment: _how to bootstrap just my service_ - what do you mean bootstrap? also, you can use DI if your other app doesn't implement it. You can import `@angular/http` and instantiate it yourself inside the class

Comment: This is my first Angular\Typescript experiment so perhaps I am making it a bigger deal that it is. How do I go about doing what you describe? Can you please describe the process? won't I need to chase after @angular/http 's dependencies as well?

Comment: sure you will need `http` dependencies as well. start a new project, create a module with one exported class, install `@angular/http`, import `@angular/http`, write simple js file and import your class. use a loader like systemjs or bundler like webpack. test that your class is working

Comment: But, he asked *"I need to re-use this ng service in an entirely different application which is vanilla JS (**no angular**, no typescript)."*. I am maybe not understanding but why are we telling him to import `@angular/http`? Shouldn't he find a way of replicating his service with just JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery, etc *(no angular, no typescript)*?

Answer (score 0):

You could still use *modern* JavaScript. Using `ECMAScript6`.

Example of a Modular HTTP request *(easily reusable throughout your App)*:

```
export default obj => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(obj.method || "GET", obj.url);
        if (obj.headers) {
            Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(obj.body);
    });
};
```

**Update 1:**

Useful documentation for building the equivalent of your Angular2 http service in ECMAScript6 (JavaScript):

- [Modularizing HTTP Requests](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/modules/)
- [Promises and AJAX in ECMAScript 6](https://shellmonger.com/2015/03/24/promises-and-ajax-in-ecmascript-6/)
- [Promisifying XMLHttpRequest](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/promisify/)

Comment: Is this an example of using JS inside an Angular app? Because my scenario is the opposite (using a TS\NG service in a JS app)

Comment: @itaysk This is an example of building an HTTP request as a module with ECMAScript6 (JavaScript). No Angular envolved. I thought this was what you asked...

Comment: Not sure I understand this solution. Are you suggesting to replace @angular/http inside the ng service with this implementation? Or maybe you meant to use this instead of reusing my existing ng service?

Comment: @itaysk I meant to use this *(and the solutions you find the useful links that I put in my Update)* instead of the service. Is basically the same as a basic NG/TS http service, but it's entirelly JavaScript. I would take this approach, instead of adapt just create it. Is very, very similar if you realize.

Comment: @itaysk If you check those links (are very well explained in my opinion), you will find some examples. Replicate them and you are done: No Angular, No TypeScript. 

And with the modular approach, you just declare this http service once and reuse it throughout your entire App, just like an Angular service behaves.